# Kotlin: Get superclass from class object - object inference error

Tags: kotlin

The following code should iterate through the chain of superclasses of the passed object's class until the top-level is reached.

```
protected fun getBestMethodFor(o: Any): Method? {
    val nodeClass = o.javaClass
    val objectClass = Any::class.java
    ...

    // Go through superclasses.
    var c = nodeClass
    while (c != objectClass && ans == null) {
        debugMsg("Looking for class match for " + c.name)
        ...
        c = c.superclass
    }
    ...
}
```

This results in 2 errors:

```
Error:(57, 17) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Class<in Any!>! but Class<Any> was expected
Error:(57, 19) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Class<in Any!>! but Class<Any> was expected
```

Why is this failing, and what do I need to change to fix this?

Note: The code was automatically converted from Java using IntelliJ's converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, [`Class<T>.getSuperClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass) returns `Class<? super T>`. The equalivant of this in Kotlin is `Class<in T>`.

In your code, `var c = nodeClass` has an implicit type of `Class<Any>`, which is not compatible with `Class<in T>`.

To fix this, simply specify the type c directly:

`var c: Class<in Any> = nodeClass`